# Hash mismatch installing DeepDarts requirements

Tags: python, pip, conda, sha, miniconda

I tried to follow [these installation instructions](https://github.com/wmcnally/deep-darts) because I want to test DeepDarts for a Dart-Counter. It's my first time with Anaconda, also the first time with Python.
After Step 4, I got this error message:

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    tensorflow==2.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/dc/9030097e5774fe02d1be3cb42eb54125d2c0607a6c11172f1dcad2b7fdcc/tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=36a4ce9bbc9865385c1bb606fe34f0da96b0496ce3997e652d2b765a4382fe48 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)):
        Expected sha256 36a4ce9bbc9865385c1bb606fe34f0da96b0496ce3997e652d2b765a4382fe48
             Got        902c8207fd779c621f08bea3da1049a0e0b5f2bd71b3d0a672025200590afa19
```

Is this important, or could I safely ignore it? And how should I update the hashes?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a windows machine. You could try to clear `pip`'s cache with `pip cache purge` and then retry the command